# how to concatenate img src string using $i

Tags: php

I have trouble to concatenate img src string.
Instead of $row['img1'] I need $row['img$i']
How would I do correct concatenation using $i?

```
 <?php $i = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
    <?php $item_class = ($i == 1) ? 'item active' : 'item'; ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $item_class; ?>">

            <img src="<?php echo '/img/post/' . $row['img1'].'.jpg'; ?>" alt="<?php echo $myrow['title']; ?>" />

      </div>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: `"img{$i}"` or `'img'.$i`, unless I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `$row['img'.$i]` or `$row["img$i"]` . String concatnation can be still used.